# UILabel not respecting truncate

Tags: ios, swift2, uilabel, truncate

This is puzzling me for a while. This is my code:

```
 let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, obTextRect.width, obTextRect.height))
            label.text = stText
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
            label.font = obDrawItem.m_obFont
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
            label.layer.drawInContext(obContext)


            CGContextRestoreGState(obContext)
```

and this is the result I am getting...

```
proceedin
g
```

The word "proceeding" does not "auto shrink" to fit the width.
Also if I add a line break (\n) then it works ok.
Any ideas???

Comment: Multiline and scale dont work together. Scale and truncation dont work together. Choose the options you want to use, dont try to use them all together.

Comment: I've got the EXACT same code in a different view and works ABSOLUTELY fine. Commenting the scale or truncation is not resolving the issue.

Comment: As you have written the code, it works correctly as described in the documentation.

Comment: @Sulthan So the above image is, according to the documentation, correct? What is then, the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The code works absolutely correctly. Why?

1. The text doesn't shrink because it fits into its frame.
2. The text doesn't use truncation because it fits into its frame.
3. Word wrapping is ignored because the word doesn't fit into single line.

I would advise you to set wrapping properties dynamically, depending on content. If the text has only one word, then set `numberOfLines` to `1`, otherwise set it to `0` or `2-3`. That will fix most of your problems.

```
let multipleWords = stText.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()) != nil
label.numberOfLines = multipleWords ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: I've got more than 100 strings that have different number of lines (ranging from 1 line to 20). I do not want to go through each one of them to see which fits and which doesn't fit. If the word is not able to fit in one line then it should shrink... This is what I would expect. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @GeorgeAsda That's the problem, you have conflicting rules. You tell the label to use multiple lines and you want it to autoshrink when it wants to use multiple lines. If you have a good architecture, you can put that code into one place and it will work correctly everywhere.

Comment: How is this working "fine"??? When I'm telling UILabel to wordWrap even if it has millions of lines to expand it stops at 4 lines. It doesn't respect the adjustFontToFitSize....

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Don't blame the framework. As I said, you have conflicting rules.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
```

Setting numberOfLines to 0 makes the label multi-line.

Comment: This is a multiline label... I need them to be multiline...and this is what I have already! thanks

Comment: I think you also want to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth for your label.